# In neovim, how to have keybinding <C-w> not wait for additional key press and execute directly?

Tags: lua, neovim

I know I have not phrased my question too clearly so I will make it more so here. We know that vim / neovim have a series of * keybindings, such as c to close a window.

Now, I have this setting of keybindings:

```lua
local map = vim.api.nvim_set_keymap
local opt = { noremap = true, silent = true }

map("n", "sc", "<C-w>c", opt) -- Close current window
map("n", "so", "<C-w>o", opt) -- Close all windows but the current
-- ... and some other mapping <C-w>* to key combinations

map("n", "<C-w>", ":bdelete!<CR>", opt)
```

At the very last, I map `<C-w>` to closing the current buffer. However, I have for much time been troubled that my using this keybinding is extremely slow in closing the buffer, with quite a perceivable delay than calling `:bdelete!` alone.

I suspect that neovim is waiting, when I have pressed `ctrl` and `w`, for another key, and will only use my `<C-w>` keybinding when no further key press is detected, which thereby gives rise to this delay.

Suppose I am correct in my hypothesis, is there a way in preventing this? Or is this delay actually due to some other reason hitherto unknown to me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<nowait>` (`:help :map-<nowait>`):

```
:nnoremap <silent> <nowait> <C-w> :bdelete!<CR>
```